# Can civicrm_mailing_bounce_pattern patterns be edited or supplemented?

Tags: civimail, bounce, bounce-processing

I am thinking it would be useful to refine or add to the bounce patterns that are stored in civicrm_mailing_bounce_pattern to more accurately capture bounce situations. It looks like the "pattern" field is just a literal string (including options separated by | chars) that the system would grep for through incoming messages. I not sure if the subject line is searched or just the body. But is there any downside to going down that road? It looks simple enough but the inner workings of bounce processing are a bit mysterious.

Edit: and it seems like this is a subject where the community could share ideas to contribute back to the devs, since very likely we all get the same bounce messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be great to have more active updates for the bounce patterns based on real current bounces.

I believe the bounce pattern only finds regex matches in the [body of the email.](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php#L143) It is indeed pretty simple.

If you want to propose some changes or additions, the issue queue would be the place to do that.

Comment: Great. One thing I've noticed is that if a bounce message comes in that does not match any pattern, then civimail moves it to "processed" state but it doesn't do anything else, so it is basically ignored, silently. So there is no default action, even though the bounce means something is wrong. That seems less than ideal.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Probably a good idea to open an issue and post some examples of bounces that you are receiving that aren't getting matched at all.